# Recorrer un Array con JQuery traído desde un value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Buenas les planteo lo que estoy realizando estoy consultando mis pedidos para así confirmar si ese producto ya se a pedido con anterioridad primero consulto con  PHP desde mi base de datos y le asigno la consulta  aun input así:

PHP:

```
$ConsultaPedidos0 = "SELECT Productos FROM PedidosAlmacen WHERE ParaAlmacenID = '$IDAlmacen' AND IDSucursal = '$IDSucursal' AND Estado = 'Enviado' ";
$resultado1 = mysqli_query($con, $ConsultaPedidos0);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado1)) {
         $pedidos = $row['Productos'];
         $PedidosArray[] = $pedidos;
         var_dump($pedidos);
         }
```

HTML/input

```
<input type="hidden" name="ProdcutosConsultados" id="ProdcutosConsultados" value='<?var_dump($PedidosArray) ?>'>
```

el valor del input se ve así:

```
value="array(9) {
  [0]=>
  string(87) "[{"id": "599", "codigo": "1004", "cantidad": "1", "descripcion": "3 EN 1 DISEÑO XIA"}]"
  [1]=>
  string(88) "[{"id": "597", "codigo": "1002", "cantidad": "1", "descripcion": "3 EN 1 DISEÑO MOTO"}]"
  [2]=>
  string(87) "[{"id": "599", "codigo": "1004", "cantidad": "1", "descripcion": "3 EN 1 DISEÑO XIA"}]"
  [3]=>
  string(88) "[{"id": "597", "codigo": "1002", "cantidad": "1", "descripcion": "3 EN 1 DISEÑO MOTO"}]"
  [4]=>
  string(88) "[{"id": "597", "codigo": "1002", "cantidad": "1", "descripcion": "3 EN 1 DISEÑO MOTO"}]"
  [5]=>
  string(88) "[{"id": "597", "codigo": "1002", "cantidad": "1", "descripcion": "3 EN 1 DISEÑO MOTO"}]"
  [6]=>
  string(88) "[{"id": "597", "codigo": "1002", "cantidad": "1", "descripcion": "3 EN 1 DISEÑO MOTO"}]"
  [7]=>
  string(88) "[{"id": "597", "codigo": "1002", "cantidad": "1", "descripcion": "3 EN 1 DISEÑO MOTO"}]"
  [8]=>
  string(88) "[{"id": "597", "codigo": "1002", "cantidad": "1", "descripcion": "3 EN 1 DISEÑO MOTO"}]"
}
"
```

y en el JQuery pensaba recocerlo algo mas o menos así pero no me funciona claramente:

```
   var consulta =  $("#ProdcutosConsultados").val();

   var n = consulta.length; 
   for(var i = 0;i<n;i++){
       console.log(consulta[i]);
  }
```

lo que quiero es poder comparar los códigos del array con los códigos a los que se quieren unir al pedido y si en dado caso los códigos son iguales pues no se pueden agregar los productos, pero lo que  quiero aprender es como recorro mi array que consulte con php para saber los códigos que tengo alojados en la consulta.

Answer (score 0):

`var_dump()` es para depurar código. Devuélvelo como JSON al cliente y podrás leerlo sin mayor dificultad.

Además, conviene llenar tu array dentro del `while` e imprimirlo al final.

Algo así:

```
$PedidosArray=array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado1)) {
    $PedidosArray[] = $row['Productos'];
}
echo json_encode($PedidosArray);
```

En Javascript, dependiendo del contexto, podrías necesitar el uso de `JSON.parse` o no. Por ejemplo, si es una petición Ajax o Fetch y ya indicaste el tipo de retorno, solamente puedes pasar a leer tu array dentro de un bucle. De hecho, es extraño que despliegues este tipo de resultados en un `input`  ¿?

```
var consulta =  $("#ProdcutosConsultados").val();
var myJson=JSON.parse(consulta);
myJson.forEach(function(item){
    console.log(`${item.id}\t${item.codigo}\t${item.cantidad}\n`);
});
```

Conviene también que, en el servidor, controles el flujo, y pongas cabeceras adecuadas indicando la codificación. JSON es delicado, y si tienes acentos por ejemplo y no manejas bien la codificación, tendrás un JSON inválido y el código fallará en el cliente. No abundo más sobre eso porque falta contexto en el código que nos muestras.

Si hay alguna duda, pregunta en comentarios debajo de la respuesta.

Comment: arrojo mi resultado a un input para poder así traer el valor de la consulta ya que la petición Ajax la uso en otra consulta  que me trae los productos que requieren ser surtidos de nuevo, entonces en mi ```input``` el value debo ponerlo asi : ``` value='<? echo $PedidosArray ?>' ``` luego de hacer lo de JQuery me de devuelve el resultado letra por letra y agrega las etiquetas PHP asi : 
p
h
p
  
e
c
h
o
  
j
s
o
n
_
e
n
c
o
d
e
(
$
a
r
a
y
_
e
s
p
e
c
i
f
i
c
a
c
i
o
n
e

Comment: @Adiel no es correcto ese modo de proceder. Ten en cuenta que Ajax sirve para traer todo aquello que necesites del servidor, sea en una petición, si ya sabes todo lo que necesitas en esa petición. sea en varias peticiones, en el caso de que haya datos dinámicos/cambiantes, como por ejemplo, las ciudades de una provincia, cada vez que el usuario cambia de provincia y cosas así. Meter ese tipo de resultados en un `input` no es correcto. Debes armar un array en PHP con todo lo que necesites, devolverlo con `echo json_encode` y en Javascript consumir ese JSON según la estructura que tenga.

Comment: perfecto ya lo realice como me indicas pero mi `json_encode` se ve algo asi : `"[{\"id\": \"599\", \"codigo\": \"1004\", \"cantidad\": \"1\", \"descripcion\": \"3 EN 1 DISE\u00d1O XIA\"}]",` como puedo solucionarlo ?

Comment: Como dije antes, falta contexto en tu pregunta. Edita la pregunta y pon tu llamada Ajax para poder ayudarte mejor. Si pones un dataType JSON no deberías tener ningún problema. También te comenté algo de la codificación, conviene que pongas esto antes del `echo` en PHP: `header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");` pero es preciso ver el tipo de datos que estás diciendo al cliente que devolverá el servidor.

Comment: la verdad ya cambie mucho el código ya lo realice de otra manera, el punto es que ahora tengo como resultado del `php` esto : `["1004"]` ahora pienso como puedo pasar ese valor a un numero en `jquery` para poder usarlo en las comparaciones, sabes como hacerlo o debería hacer otra pregunta ?

Comment: @Adiel es más de lo mismo, cualquier dato o grupo de datos que se generen en el servidor los puedes obtener en jQuery (Javascript), si es en una petición Ajax el dato estará en el bloque `success` o `done`, cuando la petición haya terminado. Si esperas un valor único, no un JSON, es mejor que emitas ese valor único, así podrás recuperarlo directamente sin manejos complicados. Si el problema es diferente ahora quizá sea mejor que abras una nueva pregunta, mostrando el contexto, tanto de la parte de jQuery como de la parte de PHP donde devuelves el dato.

Comment: Sea como sea, conviene saber que tú puedes manejar un dato simple o muchos datos estructurados... el concepto es siempre el mismo. El dato se genera en el servidor (PHP) y es consumido en el cliente (Javascript/jQuery) usando modos de lectura acordes a lo que el servidor está respondiendo (dato simple, un JSON, un XML, contenido HTML, etc). Si tú necesitas varios datos, puedes recogerlos todos en una sola llamada y luego sólo te preocupas por leerlos en el cliente. Si los datos son dinámicos o dependen de información que proporciona el cliente, entonces harás una llamada por cada nuevo dato.